# Conflicting types error and invalid type argument of unary * have int

Tags: c++, c

I have very simple program here, I get errors like :

```
conflicting type of 'f' 

previous declaration of 'f' was here

error : initializer element is not computable at load time 

in function queue_ready: 

invalid type argument of unary '*' (have'int') 

in function dequeue_ready : 

invalid type argument of unary '*' (have'int')
```

Where are my mistakes?

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int Queue_ready[1000]; 
int *r ;
int *f ; 
r=&Queue_ready[0];
f=&Queue_ready[0];

void queue_ready (int process) 
{
   *r=process; 
    r = r+1;
} 

void dequeue_ready (void) 
{
   *f = 10000; 
   f=f+1;
}

int main() 
{
   queue_ready(1); 
   queue_ready(2);
   printf("%d %d" , Queue_ready[0] ,Queue_ready[1]); 
   dequeue_ready();
   dequeue_ready();
   return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
int *r;
int *f; 
r=&Queue_ready[0];
f=&Queue_ready[0];
```

These lines lie outside of a function.  The first two are OK, since they *declare* variables, but the next two are not since they are *statements*, and statements are not allowed outside of a function.

The reason you're getting a "conflicting type" error is because the *statement* (that the compiler isn't expecting) is being read as a *declaration*.  Since this "declaration" doesn't specify a type, it has an implied type of `int` which conflicts with the prior definition of type `int *`.

Because what you actually want to do is *initialize* these variables (as opposed to assign), you do so at the time they are declared:

```
int *r = &Queue_ready[0];
int *f = &Queue_ready[0];
```

Comment: +1. The general principle here is **initialize variables when they are created**. I'm amazed at the amount of beginner code that does just what the code in the question does: define a variable, then assign an initial value to it. Do it in one step!